# Oracle Hierarchical query - how to start with selected node

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a hierarchical query for the below table but not able to get the data in the format i need..

Here is the data in the table:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| ITEM_ID | FATHER_ID | DESCRIPTION |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
|    1019 |      1018 | Level 4     |
|    1018 |      1010 | Level 3     |
|    1010 |         2 | Level 2     |
|       2 |         0 | Level 1     |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

here is the query i came up with after lot of googling:

```
SELECT
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(DESCRIPTION, '\') AS "Path"
FROM
STRUCTURE
START WITH ITEM_ID = 1019
CONNECT BY PRIOR FATHER_ID = ITEM_ID
```

The output i am getting is :

```
+---------------------------+
| \Level 4                  |
| \Level 4\Level 3          |
| \Level 4\Level 3\Level 2  |
| \Level 4\Level 3\Level 1  |
| \Level 4\Level 3\Level 1\ |
+---------------------------+
```

but how to get something like this(just one row):

`\Level 1\Level 2\Level 3\Level 4`

What am i missing in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the root of your levels and as suggested on the comment filter the `item_id` you want. Also you inverted the `connect by` statement. The right query for the problem on your question is:

```
 SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(description, '\') AS Path
   FROM STRUCTURE
  WHERE ITEM_ID = 1019
CONNECT BY PRIOR ITEM_ID = FATHER_ID
  START WITH FATHER_ID = 0;
```

But if you do not know the last item of your levels just do as this:

```
 SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(description, '\') AS Path
   FROM STRUCTURE
  WHERE ITEM_ID = (select max(item_id) from STRUCTURE)
CONNECT BY PRIOR ITEM_ID = FATHER_ID
  START WITH FATHER_ID = 0;
```

But be aware that this second query is just for a model that is ordered and the last level is the final one.

See it here on **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c5b0/4)**

Comment: Thank you so much Jorge Campos for looking into this. I am really sorry for the delay. You are Awesome.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)